# If $z=(x+y)f(ax+by)$ show that $(b(\partial z/ \partial x)-a(\partial z/ \partial y))(x-y)=(b-a)z$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

If $z=(x+y)f(ax+by)$ show that $(b(\partial z/ \partial x)-a(\partial z/ \partial y))(x-y)=(b-a)z$.

I don't really know where to start. I have written the total derivative for $f$ and $z$ assuming that $f=f(x,y)$ and $z=z(x,y)$ but It doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation $f(ax+by)$ implies that $f$ only takes one real number as an argument, so $f = f(x,y)$ is incorrect. $z = z(x,y)$ is correct.

First compute the partial derivatives of $z$:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial z}{ \partial x} &= f(ax+by) + (x+y)f'(ax+by)a \\
\frac{\partial z}{ \partial y} &= f(ax+by) + (x+y)f'(ax+by)b
\end{align*}
Now
\begin{align*}
\left(b\frac{\partial z}{ \partial x} -a\frac{\partial z}{ \partial y}  \right) (x-y) &= \left( bf(ax+by)-af(ax+by) \right) (x-y) \\
&= (b-a)f(ax+by)(x-y) \\
&=(b-a)z
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you. May you please explain why "The notation f(ax+by) implies that f only takes one real number as an argument, so f=f(x,y) is incorrect. z=z(x,y) is correct." I find it difficult to understand 'what is a function of what' and also the notation f(ax+by). Thanks

Comment: Well, $a, b, x, y$ seem to be real numbers, so $ax + by$ is a real number. Now $f(ax+by)$ means $f(g(x,y))$, where $g(x,y) = ax+by$. The function $g: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ takes $2$ arguments, so $g = g(x,y)$. But because $g(x,y) = ax +by$ is a single real number, $f(ax+by)$ is a function that takes a single argument. This is why the notation $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is very useful in multivariable calculus, where we often have functions with different domains and codomains.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed you've been very helpful.